# url rewriting of IIS

Tags: regex, iis, web-config

with some hit and trail, i managed to remove the extention of the pages which i view for my website, now i want to replace all the `?` and `=` and the `&` signs with backslash `/`, I am really Lost now, how do i write that rule in my web config

My Web.Config File:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect .cfm extension" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="^(.*).cfm$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).cfm$" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="hide .cfm extension" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.cfm" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.cfm" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

with the above, i managed to get a page like this

```
http://website.ca/graphics?mode=Graphics%20Design%20%C2%BB%20Business%20cards&catID=35&section=graphics
```

the `graphics?` is the one which was before `graphics.cfm?`

Comment: Which URL are you expecting to get instead of `http://website.ca/graphics?mode=Graphics%20Design%20%C2%BB%20Business%20cards&catID=35&section=graphics ` It will help me understand better what you trying to achieve

Comment: `http://website.ca/graphics/mode/Graphics Design » Business cards/ca‌​tID/35/section/graph‌​ics`